# Why 0000-00-00 value convert to 30/11/-1 with date %d/%m/%Y?

Tags: php, date, joomla, if-statement

Working with this code

```
<?php echo JHTML::Date($field, "%d/%m/%Y");
?>
```

everything convert like a charm but
when the value is sets to 0000-00-00, my date function convert it to 30/11/-1.

I need a IF like:

if value= 0000-00-00
output= echo "no date avaiable"

Thank you

Comment: info about jhtml http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/HTML/JHTML.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the documentation for JHTML::Date

> Returns formated date according to
>   current local and adds time offset

This means that when converting the date, the timezone will be added, probably meaning that GMT+ zones would result a negative year.

Try adjusting the offset parameter for the function.

EDIT:

```
<?php 
    echo JHTML::Date($field, "%d/%m/%Y", -4); 
    /* The third param represents the timezone offset, set it t your timezone 
       and it should work as expected */
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how `JHTML::Date`, nobody can answer you

but you can impose an additional checking like

```
if ($field=='0000-00-00' || $field==0)
{
  echo 'no date available';
}
else
{
  echo JHTML::Date($field, "%d/%m/%Y");
}
```

Details on [`JHTML::Date`](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/HTML/JHTML.html#date), which using [`strftime`](http://php.net/strftime)